# Can we include tag-wiki associations in SEDE?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, data-explorer, tag-wiki

Is it possible to include the tag-wiki associations in the Data Explorer? To do this would require two additional columns in the `postTags` table that associate a tag wiki excerpt and a tag wiki to their tag.

The tag wiki data is already available in the `posts` table. But there is no way to associate this data with its tags. The SEDE schema lacks the required columns to link the tag excerpt and the tag wiki to the tags table.

Additionally, the `postTypes` table only lists three posts types. It makes no mention of tag-wiki and tag excerpt posts. Perhaps the `postypes` table can be updated to reflect the additional post types?

Comment: This would actually go in the Tags table directly, since there's only ever a single wiki and wiki excerpt for each tag.

Comment: @Jon, good point. I confused myself.

Comment: This is about Data Explorer http://data.stackexchange.com/ and not about downloadable data dump file http://www.clearbits.net/creators/146-stack-exchange-data-dump

Answer (score 4):

This was added at some point:

**Tags** table

- ExcerptPostId *int*
- WikiPostId *int*

The PostTypes table lists all exported post types as well.

Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/167810?TagName=c%23

Answer (score 2):

Now the tag wiki details are available in the Posts under the "PostTypeId" = 5.

If you want to see the tag wiki contents you can write a simple query like below;

select *
from Posts p
where p.PostTypeId = 5