# readme.txt for data dump doesn't describe all post types

Tags: bug, data-dump

`Stack Exchange Data Dump - Mar 2013/Content/readme.txt` doesn't describe all post types

Currently it is describes only question and answer types.

```
   - **posts**.xml
       - Id 
       - PostTypeId
          - 1: Question
          - 2: Answer
       - ParentID (only present if PostTypeId is 2)
       - AcceptedAnswerId (only present if PostTypeId is 1)
       - CreationDate 
       - ...
```

The posts.xml contains at least these additional types.

- 3 orphan tag wiki
- 4 tag wiki exceprt
- 5 tag wiki body
- 6 election nomination
- 7  WikiPlaceholder
- 8  PrivilegeWiki

Comment: Related posts that mention need for updating readme.txt http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99669/can-we-include-tag-wiki-associations-in-the-data-dump, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131975/what-are-the-posttypeids-in-the-2011-12-data-dump

Comment: This might be resolved by https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/302212/please-update-the-readme-txt-in-the-data-dump