# Please update the readme.txt in the Data Dump

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-dump

In the [Readme.txt](https://ia800500.us.archive.org/22/items/stackexchange/readme.txt) of the SE Data Dump found on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) the contents of each site's 7-Zip file is documented.

The fact that the tags.xml is available isn't reflected in the readme.txt.

Please add the following before `- **votes**.xml`:

```
   - **tags**.xml
       - Id
       - TagName
       - Count
       - ExcerptPostId - if an Excerpt is created
       - WikiPostId - if an Wiki is created
```

I've also noticed that at least the PostHistoryTypeId field contain values that more closely match with what is described in [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678/158100) but I only verified that for the posthistory.xml of one site so I'm not 100% sure if I'm correct on that one.

Can the readme.txt be refreshed to depict the current expected content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've updated the readme with `Tags.xml` as well as `PostLinks.xml` (both were missing), added a few missing enumeration values (not only for `PostHistoryTypeId`) and make it that little bit more consistent.

With you in the next... data dump.