# License link on SEDE archive page points to wrong BY-SA version

Tags: bug, status-completed, licensing, creative-commons, archive

On the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer Help](https://data.stackexchange.com/help) page, there is a link to the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange) page. On the Stack Exchange Archive page, there is a section for licensing, with the following description:

> All user content contributed to the Stack Exchange network is cc-by-sa 4.0 licensed, intended to be shared and remixed. We even provide all our data as a convenient data dump.
>
> License: [https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)

The license link shows as BY-SA 4.0, but the link actually points to a BY-SA 3.0 URL (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which is incorrect.

There are also multiple links on the page which still point to `http://`.

Could these be fixed?

Comment: I’ll look into this today, thanks for the report!

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the quick response.
Some of the URLs are still `http://` only. Could you please check those as well on that page?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link has been updated to point to the correct URL, and `http://` links (at least the ones in our control) now point to `https://`.

Also cleaned up some pointless links to prior years, since previous versions of any given upload simply don't exist anymore.

Comment: While there... there is list of years in that page, and the expected behavior is for each year to link to the data dump of Stack Exchange for that year. However, turns out that each year links to overall search of archive.org for the literal string e.g. [2022](https://archive.org/search?query=year%3A%222022%22), which also give semi NSFW results which were bit shocking at first. Can the links actually point to SE data dumps, or if not possible, removed? Thanks!

Comment: That's pity, any chance to contact archive.org about it? (Officially, coming from SE itself, they might even respond.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I was able to get the links to previous years removed, they don't make sense anyway because we replace an existing file with a newer version, for various reasons. However I don't think we'll be able to get [these links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r83iq.png) to not be the same type of generic search.

Comment: Thanks, there's almost nothing you can't do, or so it appears. :D

Comment: @Shadow Ok, fixed the headline searches too, by combining topic and date (it now leads to an empty search result; I can't prevent it from linking to _something_). Also changed "see the included readme" in the paragraph below to a link to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678), since we agreed last year to [stop maintaining two copies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/383323/165455).