# Is there a reason why tag pages aren't part of the data dump?

Tags: feature-request, tags, data-dump

Tag excerpts and tag wikis are cc-by-sa licensed content, just like the rest of the content, but they don't appear in the dumps. Shouldn't they be included as well?

Comment: @AmalMurali Yeah, it is, assuming that one is about the XML data dumps (which it appears to be). Must have missed that one in my search. Don't know how - it's obvious.

Comment: Happens! It's listed as the first question in the *Related* section. I found it there.

Comment: Weird, since I didn't see it in my search and it wasn't one of the "related questions" on the post preview page (at least that I saw).

Comment: @AmalMurali. That question *says* data dump, but, per the comments, is actually about the Data Explorer. It should be rewritten to make that clearer. I think the *actual* dupe is http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/176407/147191, which actually is about the data dump.