# Tag prediction for Stack Overflow posts

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

I'm working on a small project where I have to create a model (nltk) that will predict the tags from questions that may be published on Stack Overflow.

I used this link https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/new, and I was hoping there was a place that would explain more in-depth the details of the parameters.

For instance, what is "WikiPostId" in the Tags table? Most of the parameters are self-explanatory, but I fear I will miss some fine tuning.

Comment: In the [data-explorer tag-info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/data-explorer/info) you can find several useful links, including [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2677). Maybe this might help.

Comment: It seems very likely that ExcerptPostId and WikiPostId are correspond to [tag-excerpt and tag-wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/tag-wiki/info) for the given tag.
See also: [Can we include tag-wiki associations in SEDE?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99669)

Comment: You mean [this](https://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current)? Or tag suggestion feature, which suggests tags based on key words in post body?

Comment: The link that Martin gave is what I'm looking for "Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE". Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is, as Martin said, [some documentation on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) about the structure of the SEDE database.

As for your specific question, `WikiPostId` is the `Post.Id` of the tag wiki. Tag wikis are posts too, with `Posts.PostTypeId = 5` (excerpts are `4`), so you can use `Tags.WikiPostId` to look up the wiki post in the `Posts` table.